# MySQL distance calculating

Tags: mysql

I currently run a query that returns a distance column displaying the distance in miles from a given point

```
SELECT user_id, 
    SQRT(
        POW(69.1 * (lat_col - 60.454509), 2) +
        POW(69.1 * (9.667969 - lng_col) * COS(lat_col / 57.3), 2)
    ) AS distance
    FROM users ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Returns

```
user_id | distance
-------------------
1           27
56          29
8           32
32          45
4           56
6           64
```

The problem is that this distance value is in miles and i need it to be in kilometres. I can do this in `php` but I would prefer to keep things simple, fast and clean by using the current SQL I have.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because someone has neglected to engage brain.

Comment: @Strawberry You are a non constructive person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 mile = 1.609344 kilometres so we can just alter the distance:

```
SELECT user_id, 
    SQRT(
        POW(69.1 * (lat_col - 60.454509), 2) +
        POW(69.1 * (9.667969 - lng_col) * COS(lat_col / 57.3), 2)
    ) * 1.609344 AS distance
    FROM users ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can't believe I over looked this. Will mark as correct as soon as i'm allowed.

Answer (score 0):

A degree longitude is average 111 km it depends where.

Answer (score 0):

`1 Mile = 1.60934 Kilometer`. So you just need to multiply your distance calculation with `1.60934`

```
SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (lat_col - 60.454509), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * (9.667969 - lng_col) * COS(lat_col / 57.3), 2)
) * 1.60934 AS distance
```